# Getting garbage value at the end of some strings

Tags: c, string, file-handling

I scraped a website to get some mcqs for a c assignment. I wrote the data to a plaintext file separating every entry with null chars.
The pattern is: 
`Question with choices NULL Answer NULL Question...`

Here is a sample of the file. the red dots are `'\0'` chars:

[image]
[Here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=04079543418221131719) is a link to get the full file.

**Code to read this file in C**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct Question{
    char question[1000];
    char answer;
};

int main(){
struct Question questions[100];
FILE *fp;
char buffer[1000],choice;
int ch,i=0,c=1,k=0,score=0;
fp=fopen("quiz_questions.txt","r");
ch = 1;
  while (ch != EOF)
  {
    ch = getc(fp);
    buffer[i]=ch;
    i++;
    if(ch=='\0'){
    buffer[i]='\0';
    c++;
    i=0;
    continue;
    }
    if(c%2){ //question
    strcpy(questions[k].question,buffer);


    }
    else{ //answer
    questions[k].answer=buffer[0];
    k++;

    }
 }



for(i=0;i<35;i++){
printf("\nQuestion:\n%s\nAnswer: %c\n",questions[i].question,questions[i].answer);
}


return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image: Output]

What am I missing? Help please. It seems the buffer isn't getting null terminated properly and is retaining chars from last assignment.

PS: Is there a better way to consume this data from c? Scraping done via python.

EDIT: I now realize writing a separate answerkey file would have been much better. Stupid me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    strcpy(questions[k].question,buffer);
```

This statement is executed for every single character you read (if `c` is odd). At this point, `buffer` is not null terminated yet (and not a string).

```
ch = getc(fp);
buffer[i]=ch;
```

These two lines write to `buffer[i]` even if the end of file was reached. You only check for `EOF` after having processed it as if it were a normal character.

```
i++;
if(ch=='\0'){
buffer[i]='\0';
```

This is redundant. If `ch` is `'\0'`, then you've just null terminated `buffer` in `buffer[i]=ch;`. There's no need to add another `'\0'`.

Comment: the ```buffer[i]='\0'``` was added in desperation.

Answer (score 1):

Modified version of your code to solve the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct Question{
    char question[1000];
    char answer;
};

int main()
{
    struct Question questions[100];
    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[1000],choice;
    int ch,i=0,c=0,k=0,score=0;    **<-- EDIT:change done here to initialize c = 0**

    fp=fopen("quiz_questions.txt","r");

    ch = 1;

    while (ch != EOF)
    {
        ch = getc(fp);
        buffer[i]=ch;
        i++;

        if(ch =='\0')
        {
            //buffer[i]='\0';  <-- Change done here, unnecessary assignment
            c++;
            i=0;

            if(c%2)            <-- Change done here, moved inside if (ch == '\0') case
            { 
                //question
                strcpy(questions[k].question,buffer);
            }
            else
            { 
                //answer
                questions[k].answer=buffer[0];
                k++;
            }
        }
    }


    for(i=0;i<35;i++)
    {
        printf("\nQuestion:\n%s\nAnswer: %c\n",questions[i].question,questions[i].answer);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @thekindlyone, I did not test the modification since the input txt file is not available. I missed to initialize c = 0 instead of c = 1 (in original code) [It was required since I moved strcpy() code inside if (ch == '\0') loop]. I have edited the posted modified code for this change. Hope this works fine.

Comment: Hah! I missed that in my attempt to fix it too! Thanks.